# Hide Putty terminal while running from Java

Tags: java, terminal, hide, putty

I am running the following code in Java for running a shell script in Ubuntu.
But when it is running, y=the putty terminal will be displayed. But i dont want this. How will I hide this terminal.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(winBasePath + "putty.exe", "-ssh", "-m", winBasePath + "runHiveCmd.txt", linuxSystem, "-pw", linuxPwd);      
Process p = pb.start();     
try {
   p.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ProcessBuilder pb = 
  new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "START", "/MIN", winBasePath + "putty.exe", ...);
```

Comment: It will run in minimized mode. That's ok. Is there a way to completely hide it even not in minimized mode?

Comment: Putty is very much a windowed application. There has been requests for a no-terminal mode but hasnt materialized (see [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/no-terminal-window.html))

Answer (score 1):

If performing a remote command via ssh, consider jsch. This provides cleaner integration does not require ProcessBuilder.  Here is [an example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html) you could start with